# $digest already in progress when using multiple ckeditor

Tags: html, angularjs, ckeditor

I am using multiple `ckeditor` with different ids and name in my project. this works fine for the page where I have static editors, but have problem where I have dynamic editors. They do not bind to the `ng-model` of my project.

this is the directive I have created

```
angular.module('MyProjectName').directive('ckEditor', function () {
    return {
        require: '?ngModel',
        link: function (scope, elm, attr, ngModel) {
            var ck = CKEDITOR.replace(elm[0]);
            if (!ngModel) return;
            ck.on('instanceReady', function () {
                ck.setData(ngModel.$viewValue);
            });
            function updateModel() {
                scope.$apply(function () {
                    ngModel.$setViewValue(ck.getData());
                });
            }
            ck.on('change', updateModel);
            ck.on('key', updateModel);
            ck.on('dataReady', updateModel);

            ngModel.$render = function (value) {
                ck.setData(ngModel.$viewValue);
            };
        }
    };
});
```

this is the html

```
<textarea data-ck-editor id="Demo" name="Demo" ng-model="DemoValue"></textarea>
```

Comment: Try to change your `scope.$apply` to `scope.$evalAsync`.

Comment: this does not help, the model still doesnt reflect the changes

Comment: @LuizCarlos thanks for your help, I found the problem when using multiple ck editor in a single page, that are dynamically generated. The solution to this problem, I made changes in my page, changed from ng-show to ng-if and respective changes related to it. and it worked just fine.

Comment: Good to know that you've solved your problem. Congratulations!